# arduino: displaying something on my 7-segment while simoustanly playing a tune on a piezo buzzer

Tags: arduino

I am working on a project and when u press a certain button 2 things need to happen:

1. a short text needs to flow over my 4 digit 7-segment
2. a simple song needs to play with a piezo buzzer

Both things work perfectly but the problem is that i can't run them at the same time so it will first do the text and then the tune. this is my code:

```
if (digitalRead(knopTekst) == LOW) {
    song();
    text();
  }
```

The song needs to play while the text is running over the digits but I can't find how to do it.

Comment: change the `if` to `while` and write the functions `song` and `text` to do one thing and return and do next thing on next call

Comment: As Juraj indicates, you need to "time-share" between your song playing task and your text display (in this case, 7 segment refresh) task. I assume you're using a library for the display such as SevSeg. There's a method which must be called very regularly (at least once every few milliseconds) for the display to work. Your song playing must be done in  very small pieces on each call, each piece must not be more than a couple of milliseconds.